# Language and exercise a sport?

Tags: перевод, грамматика

I am curious how I write correctly that I exercise the sport тхэквондо (russian spelling for: "taekwondo"?)?
Which verb is most correct?

I am also curious how Hebrew is spelled correctly (еврейский?).

Comment: Do you mean Hebrew language or Hebrew people? These are different words in Russian.

Answer (score 1):

Я **занимаюсь** тхэквондо.

In case of other kinds of sports (like ball games as opposed to wrestling) it is also possible to use the verb "играть" (я играю в футбол, в шахматы).
The spelling "*тхэквондо*" comes from strict rules of Korean-to-Russian *practical transcription system*, not from English version of the word.

еврейский (adjective)

еврей (noun; nationality)

Comment: "Hebrew" is not nationality, it's at best "ethnicity".